# Migration: Cannot add foreign key constraint in Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel. However, when I migrate my table using Artisan, I get the following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `posts` add
>   constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`)
>   references `categories` (`id`))

**Posts migration**

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->longText('content');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->uuid('author_id');
    $table->uuid('category_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null');
});
```

**Categories migration**

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->uuid('parent')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: and which of these migrations did you create first?

Comment: Is the categories migration being run before the posts migration?

Comment: @lagbox post migration run after categories migration

Comment: @brice post migration run after categories migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `posts` schema you're setting the `author_id` and `category_id` as null on deleting, but you didn't set those fields as nullable. Changing the definition to:

```
$table->uuid('author_id')->nullable();
$table->uuid('category_id')->nullable();
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Split your foreign key declarations in to their own Schema method...

I don't understand the cause of the problem, but doing this has always worked for me.

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->longText('content');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->uuid('author_id');
    $table->uuid('category_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('set null');
});
```

Comment: the single create ends up being different queries in the end, hence the error of an `alter` query, not a `create` ... in the past though this change was often needed